# Listview - has focus always return false

Tags: android

I have an edit text in the list view. Listview is created using Base Adapter and used Holders to load the edit text.

When I cal holder.edtText.hasFocus(), it always return false. Anything that I am missing in the ListView properties?

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final   
    ViewGroup parent) 
    {                                 
    if (convertView == null) 
    {                     
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());                          

    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen, parent, false);                       
    holder = new Adapter.ViewHolder(convertView);                     
    convertView.setTag(holder);                 
    }
    else 
    {                     
    holder = (Adapter.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();           
    }                                                   
    holder.edt.setCursorVisible(holder.edt.hasFocus());                 
    holder.edt.setEnabled(true);                                  
    holder.edt.setTag(R.string.view, “some object”);
                 
    if (position == 10) 
    {                     
    holder.edt.requestFocus();                 
    }
             holder.edt.setFilters(new Filter());                          
    holder.edt.addTextChangedListener(new Watcher());                          
    holder.edt.setText(“text”);                                                                             
    holder.edt.setSelection(text.length);               
    holder.edt.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);                      
    return convertView;
             }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder 
    {                 
     public EditText edit;                          
     public ViewHolder(View itemView) 
     {                 
      super(itemView);         
      edt = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.edt);             
    }
             }
```

Comment: Show us the code.What you did?

Comment: This is a continuation question from my another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46157686/listview-multi-selector-issue?noredirect=1#comment79281723_46157686

Comment: Mention what you want to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to solve this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46157686/listview-multi-selector-issue?noredirect=1#comment79281723_46157686. and noticed that hasFocus in the code is always returning false.

Comment: what is needfocus?

Comment: updated the code

Comment: If I am correct then you want one edit text to show the blinker when it open for the first time

Comment: Correct, when you first come - I want a blinker at a specific item. And then I change in the screen. Now the problem is I do not see blinker at all. Because holder.edt.setCursorVisible(holder.edt.hasFocus());     always return false.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154173/discussion-between-shubham-agarwal-bhewanewala-and-sreeram-sunkara).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
```

to your listView

Comment: No luck, I have this.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this,

```
static boolean b= true;
if(b == true){
   et.requestFocus();
   b= false;
}
```